# OCaml: Why does this code produce a type check error?

Tags: ocaml, typechecking

Here is my code:

```
let avg l =
    List.fold_left ( +. ) 0. l /. float (List.length l);;
let variability l =
    let xbar = avg l in 
    let odp = (List.map (fun i -> ((float) i -. xbar) ** 2.0) l) in
    let sum = List.fold_left ( +. ) 0. odp in
    sum /. (float) length l;;
```

Entering this into the toplevel produces the following:

```
val avg : float list -> float = <fun>
#         Characters 107-108:
      let odp = (List.map (fun i -> ((float) i -. xbar) ** 2.0) l) in
                                                                ^
Error: This expression has type float list but is here used with type
         int list
```

I've been trying to work with this for a long time but I can't figure out why this is producting an error. Is it thinking that `l` is an int list?

**SOLUTION:** (from below. Thanks!)

```
let avg l =
    List.fold_left ( +. ) 0. l /. float (List.length l);;
let variability l =
    let xbar = avg l in 
    let odp = (List.map (fun i -> (i -. xbar) ** 2.0) l) in
    let sum = List.fold_left ( +. ) 0. odp in
    sum /. (float) (List.length l);;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let xbar = avg l` causes `l` to be inferred as type `float list`, which appears to be what you want. However, in the expression `List.map (fun i -> ((float) i -. xbar) ** 2.0) l`, you use `(float) i` in the mapping function. The type of `float` is `int -> float`, so `i` is inferred as type `int`. This causes `l` to be inferred as type `int list`, which fails to unify with `float list`, resulting in a type check error.

I believe the last line is also incorrect. It should use `List.length`, not just `length`, and I think you need parentheses around the argument to `float`, not `float` itself.

This code should work:

```
let avg l =
    List.fold_left ( +. ) 0. l /. float (List.length l);;
let variability l =
    let xbar = avg l in 
    let odp = (List.map (fun i -> (i -. xbar) ** 2.0) l) in
    let sum = List.fold_left ( +. ) 0. odp in
    sum /. float (List.length l);;
```